# Find a pointer in a std::set based on a const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, set, constants

The following code does not work because of the marked line, since `s.find` expects an `int*`, not `const int*`. Since nothing is being changed about the variable `b`, why is it not possible to call the method like that? Is there a nicer way than `const_cast`?

```
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int* a = &x;
    const int* b = a;

    std::set<int*> s;
    s.insert(a);
    s.find(b); // does not work
    s.find(const_cast<int*>(b)); // does work, but const_cast
}
```

The error is

> `error: no matching function for call to 'std::set<int*>::find(const int*&)'`

after which it tries implicit conversion and fails with

> `error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'std::set<int*>::key_type {aka int*}' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: This is one of those times where I think using `const_cast` is fine, though if you never intend to modify the set elements you could always specialise for `const int*`.

Comment: Is the C++11 tag binding?

Comment: @George Interesting. I'll wait for some other opinions, though. With specialize, you mean have the set itself be `std::set<const int*>`?

Comment: Can I mark my own question as a duplicate?

Comment: @kim366 Yeah, though obviously that may not help here, but there's nothing unsafe or even especially dirty about using `const_cast`.

Comment: @kim366 Yes, on the web browser version there should be a link, `close` between the question and comments, hit that and it should give you an option to close off as a dupe :-)

Comment: @George Found it